# How can I use python to speed up a video without dropping frames

Tags: python, video-processing, moviepy

I have a video which is 1:24 minutes long and has a fps of 10 without any sound. I need the video to go down to 28 seconds and add sound to it, without dropping frames, and evidently increase the fps. I tried to use `MoviePy` to to accomplish this.

```py
clip = VideoFileClip(in_loc)
final = clip.fx(vfx.speedx, 3)
final.write_videofile(out_loc, audio=audio_loc)
```

But when I checked details of the file, the file was still 10 fps. So this method had dropped frames.
Then I tried, the following code.

```py
clip.write_videofile(out_loc, fps=30, audio=audio_loc)
```

The resulting file was still 1:24 minutes long, although the fps attribute had increased to 30.
How can I accomplish this?

Note: All the `_loc` variables are strings that contain the location of the corresponding file.
I do not mind installing other libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the solution using the `set_fps` attribute of the `Clip` class. Indeed, the `set_fps` [function](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/Clip.html#moviepy.Clip.Clip.set_fps) returns a copy of the clip with a modified FPS count. When applying the transformation to this copy, you end up with the correct number of FPS.

As you did not provide a reproducible example, I used a [stock video](https://www.videvo.net/video/time-lapse-day-to-night-city/2644/) (renamed `dummy_in.mp4`) of 15 seconds and 24 FPS and no sound. I end up with a 5 seconds clip and 72 FPS using this code :

```py
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx

in_loc = 'dummy_in.mp4'
out_loc = 'dummy_out.mp4'

# Import video clip
clip = VideoFileClip(in_loc)
print("fps: {}".format(clip.fps))

# Modify the FPS
clip = clip.set_fps(clip.fps * 3)

# Apply speed up
final = clip.fx(vfx.speedx, 3)
print("fps: {}".format(final.fps))

# Save video clip
final.write_videofile(out_loc)
```

It produces this output :

```
fps: 23.976023976023978
fps: 71.92807192807193
Moviepy - Building video dummy_out.mp4.
Moviepy - Writing video dummy_out.mp4

Moviepy - Done !
Moviepy - video ready dummy_out.mp4
```